# Insert number of blank rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using a SQL query, I need to include blank rows in the result to make every group of `(family_id)` equal to 4 rows

```
SELECT   
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY family_id) AS rowNum,
    full_name as name, family_id
FROM
    tbl_person
```

Like this:

[image: original result]

and the result will be

[image]

Comment: I think you might need some dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: What is your desired result if a `family_id` value appears more than 4 times? return only four rows (your `ORDER BY family_id` clause makes this fairly random) or extend all `family_id` groups to the same size as the biggest `family_id` group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define a second query that builds the empty rows that you need and union them together.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY family_id) AS rowNum,
    full_name as name,
    family_id
FROM tbl_person

UNION ALL

SELECT n.N AS rowNum,
    NULL AS name,
    p.family_id
FROM (SELECT family_id, COUNT(*) family_count FROM tbl_person group by family_id) p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS N
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    ) n
    ON n.n > p.family_count
ORDER BY family_id,
    rowNum,
    name;
```

Comment: Thank you , if I have about 500 family and about 2000 person,
is that effect on the performance

Comment: Those are pretty small values.  I wouldn't think you'd have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a tally table (because it's only 4 numbers it can be inline) and you cross apply them to all family_ids, you get records of numbers 1 to 4 for each family_id. Then left joining on both nr and family_id, the result would contain 4 rows for each id's where only the data of the existing rows are filled.
(To prevent double referencing, you can use a cte on the main table to get both id's and do the left join, but you could also do the group by directly on the main table)

```
with p as
(
    SELECT   *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY family_id) AS rowNum  
    FROM tbl_person
)
select nr as row_num, full_name as name, f.family_id
from (values(1),(2),(3),(4)) as nrs(nr) --inline tally table
cross apply (select family_id from p group by family_id) f --group by family id to get all existing id's
left join  p on p.rowNum = nr and f.family_id = p.family_id
```

---

***edit***
Since you need more rows, it's easier (for creating and changing afterwards) to use some sort of tally table. One of my personal favourites is using an existing sys table:

```
with p as
(
    SELECT   *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY family_id) AS rowNum  
    FROM tbl_person
)
select nr as row_num, full_name as name, f.family_id
from (select top 14 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) nr from sys.all_columns) nrs --use sys table for tallying
cross apply (select family_id from p group by family_id) f
left join  p on p.rowNum = nr and f.family_id = p.family_id
order by family_id,nr
```

Comment: in fact i need to fill 14 rows

Comment: In that case it might be better to use a tally table. I've edited the question to add an example

Answer (score 2):

Add blank rows to last row of each group using recursive CTE:

```
with Q as(
 SELECT full_name as name, age, family_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY family_id) AS rowNum,
        count(1) over(partition by family_id) cnt
   FROM tbl_person
 union all
  select NULL,NULL,family_id, Q.rowNum+1, Q.rowNum+1
    from Q
   where Q.cnt=Q.rowNum and Q.rowNum < 4
)
select * from Q
 order by family_id, rowNum
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a cte Tally table to build a skeleton based on your unique `family_id` values, and cte Results table which can be left joined to the skeleton based on tally number = row number.

```
Declare @family_row_count int = 14;

-- Tally Table CTE script (SQL 2005+ only)
-- You can use this to create many different numbers of rows... for example:
-- You could use a 3 way cross join (t3 x, t3 y, t3 z) instead of just 2 way to generate a different number of rows.
-- The # of rows this would generate for each is noted in the X3 comment column below.
-- For most common usage, I find t3 or t4 to be enough, so that is what is coded here.
-- If you use t3 in ‘Tally’, you can delete t4 and t5.


; WITH
    -- Tally table Gen            Tally Rows:     X2                X3
t1 AS (SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 1 N),    -- 4            ,    8
t2 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t1 x, t1 y),            -- 16            ,    64
t3 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t2 x, t2 y),            -- 256            ,    4096
t4 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t3 x, t3 y),            -- 65536        ,    16,777,216
t5 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t4 x, t4 y),            -- 4,294,967,296,    A lot
Tally AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) N
          FROM t3 x, t3 y) -- Change the t3's to one of the other numbers above for more/less rows 

, cte_Skeleton
as (
    select
         tally.N as [row_number]
         , family.family_id
    from Tally tally
    cross join ( select family_id from tbl_person group by family_id ) family
    where tally.N <= @family_row_count
)

, cte_person
as
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY family_id) AS rowNum
        , full_name as name
        , family_id
    FROM tbl_person
)

select
      skeleton.[row_number] as [rowNum]
    , person.name
    , person.age
    , skeleton.family_id

from cte_Skeleton skeleton

left join cte_person person
    on person.family_id = skeleton.family_id
    and person.rownum = skeleton.[row_number]
```

NB, because you've defined the skeleton first and are left joining to it, even if a family_id contains more than 14 people, only the first 14 will have skeleton rows to match in the join.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution for any number of people
(SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00677/25):

```
WITH 

maxRow AS (
  SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) maxRow FROM tbl_person GROUP BY family_id ORDER BY 1 DESC 
),

rn AS (
  SELECT 1 as rowNum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rowNum + 1
  FROM rn 
  WHERE rowNum < (SELECT * FROM maxRow)
),

rnFi AS (
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  rn,
  (SELECT DISTINCT family_id FROM tbl_person) fi
)

SELECT
  rnFi.rowNum,
  rnFi.family_id,
  t.name
FROM
  rnFi
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT   
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_id ORDER BY family_id) AS rowNum,
    family_id,
    name
  FROM
    tbl_person) t ON rnFi.family_id = t.family_id AND rnFi.rowNum = t.rowNum
ORDER BY
  2, 1
;
```