# How to return null values on serial no if not exists instead of row number() in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query is returning NULL values on ROW NUMBER() with partition to LotNo,
How to change this query so that it returns nulls on a integer column serial no

```
with p as  
(  
    SELECT   LotNo,  
Jeans,  
Marka,  
BagsFill,  
Rate,  
Purchased_quantity,  
Purchased_Weight,  
Sold_quantity,  
Sold_weight,  
Stock_qty,  
Stock_weight,**ROW_NUMBER()** OVER(PARTITION BY LotNo ORDER BY LotNo) as SerialNo   
    FROM tbl_STOCK  
)  
select nr as SerialNo, f.LotNo,Jeans,Marka,BagsFill,Rate,Purchased_quantity,  
Purchased_Weight,Sold_quantity,Sold_weight,Stock_qty,Stock_weight  
from (select top (select MAX(SerialNo) from uniqueRows) ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) nr from sys.all_columns) nrs --use sys table for tallying  
cross apply (select LotNo from p group by LotNo) f  
left join  p on p.SerialNo = nr and f.LotNo = p.LotNo  
order by LotNo,nr
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. [edit] your title to change the all-caps text to a normal capitalized text.

Comment: provide a sample data and the desired output

Comment: Just a guess, but most certainly "left join  p on p.SerialNo" doesn't find a match - that's why you receive NULL.... so, what do you expect in case the match of the left join isn't fulfilled?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063821/insert-number-of-blank-rows-in-sql